# How to import helm resources using terarform

Tags: terraform, helm3, infrastructure

Can anyone help me in importing the below helm resources using terraform inside tf state file?

```
helm ls
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                 STATUS  CHART       APP VERSION
portworx    default     1       2022-08-25 06:01:24.991655337 +0000 UTC deployed    portworx-1.0.32 2.9.1.4
```

I tried by running terraform import helm_release.px default/portworx  -lock=false but getting below error:

```
terraform import helm_release.px default/portworx  -lock=false
The import command expects two arguments.
Usage: terraform [global options] import [options] ADDR ID

  Import existing infrastructure into your Terraform state.

  This will find and import the specified resource into your Terraform
  state, allowing existing infrastructure to come under Terraform
  management without having to be initially created by Terrafor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import you need to do your -lock=false option first instead of last

terraform import -lock=false helm_release.px default/portworx

Comment: Getting below error whlle trying above cmd                                                    helm_release.px: Importing from ID "default/portworx"...
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
│ 
│ 
╵

Comment: awesome, now your terraform command is correct and the issue you're facing is one with your `KUBE_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable not being set, expired credentials, or some other local issue. If you're using AWS this thread will be useful to read through https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1234

Comment: Can you please guide me in respect to updating the above helm resources using terraform ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean creating a resource to manage the helm release you've imported?